# Was bedeutet „auf Draht sein“?

Tags: meaning, idiom

Was meint man mit „auf Draht“ (lit. “on the wire”)? Or what is the English equivalent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Die Redewendung

> Auf Draht sein

soll verdeutlichen, dass jemand besonders aufmerksam bei seiner Sache ist.

Ihren Ursprung hat diese Redewendung in den Anfängen der Telekommunikation, als mit Hilfe der Telegrafie über einen elektrischen **Draht** eine Nachricht rasch auch über weite Strecken übermittelt werden konnte (Quelle: [Geo](http://www.geo.de/GEOlino/mensch/redewendungen/deutsch/50994.html)).

> To be on the ball

Schlägt [Leo](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=auf%20Draht%20sein) als Übersetzung vor.

Answer (score 9):

[Wiktionary führt für die Redewendung *"auf Draht sein"*](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/auf_Draht_sein) folgende Bedeutung

> *umgangssprachlich*: aufmerksam sein und im entscheidenden Moment das Richtige tun

Manchmal wird auch das Wort "schwer" verstärkend verwendet, z. B.: *"Bettina ist schwer auf Draht*."

Ich persönlich empfinde eine Person *"auf Draht"*, wenn sie kompetent ist und in schwierigen Situation schnell und gut reagiert.

Auf Englisch könnte der Satz "Er ist auf Draht." mit

> He knows his stuff.

oder

> He's [always] on the ball.

übersetzt werden.

Ahnliche deutsche Redewendungen sind

- auf Zack sein
- top-fit sein
- etwas auf dem Kasten haben